# loaddup_pd/unpacklo_pd on Xeon Phi

Tags: vectorization, sse, avx, intel-mic, xeon-phi

If I have the following doubles in a 512-wide SIMD vector, as in a Xeon Phi register:

```
m0 = |b4|a4|b3|a3|b2|a2|b1|a1|
```

is it possible to make it into:

```
m0_d = |a4|a4|a3|a3|a2|a2|a1|a1|
```

using a single instruction?
Also since there are no bitwise intrinsics for doubles is this still a valid way to achieve the above?

```
m0_t = _mm512_swizzle_pd(m9,_MM_SWIZ_REG_CDAB);//m0_t->|a4|b4|a3|b3|a2|b2|a1|b1|
__m512d res = _mm512_mask_or_epi64(m0,k1,zero,m0_t);//k1 is 0xAA
```

Comment: Actually this can be accomplished by:

    m0_d=_mm512_mask_swizzle_pd(m0,0xAA,m0,_MM_SWIZ_REG_CDAB);

Overlooked the mask variant..

Comment: If that solution works, you might consider adding it as an answer so it is easier to find. The Xeon Phi is still very new, so there isn't a lot of best-practices information out there yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be achieved as follows:

```
m0_d = _mm512_mask_swizzle_pd(m0,0xAA,m0,_MM_SWIZ_REG_CDAB);
```

It might seem that the swizzle operation is limited, but with the masked variant we can achieve other permutations too.